# How to download excel sheet which fetch resultset from database

Tags: java, mysql, excel, jsp, servlets

I have used Apache POI library and generated excel sheet from database using query to obtain list of doctors and their details. I have to go to the below mentioned location "C:\Users\Mohan\Downloads\data.xls" to check my excel file.
But how to download it in browser when i click button in jsp.

protected void doGet(.......) throws Exception{

```
    HSSFWorkbook hwb=new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("doctors");

    HSSFRow rowhead=   sheet.createRow((short)0);

    rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Doctor ID");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Name");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("UserName");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Contact No");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("E-mail");

    DoctorDao dao = new DoctorDao();
    ResultSet res = dao.getdoctors();

    int i = 1;
    try {
        while(res.next()){
            HSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)i);
            row.createCell((short)0).setCellValue(Integer.toString(res.getInt(1)));
            row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(res.getString(2));
            row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(res.getString(3));
            row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(res.getString(4));
            row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(res.getString(5));
            i++;
            }
        String filename="C:\\Users\\Mohan\\Downloads\\data.xls";
        FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(filename);
        hwb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: store the file in server context

Comment: Thank you @Sumesh but could you eloborate more how to store the file in server context and download it?

Comment: Store the file using request.getServletContext()+File.seperator+filename location. Then do the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a simple redirect: `response.sendRedirect("URL TO THE EXCEL SHEET")`
By the way this is a simple download there are better ways but this one is ok and it works. If you use this method the file needs to be in the /WebContent folder or if ot is generated at runtime in the /webapps/yourappsname/ folder

In this case the file is at `/var/share/tomcat/webapps/assets/list.xls` the URL will be `assets/list.xls`

the other option is something like this:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\FILEURL\\whatever\\whatever.xls"));
while(in.avainable()>0){
     getWriter().write(in.read());
}
```

But pay attention to this and read this post:[Java : download file outside server context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074848/java-download-file-outside-server-context)

Comment: Thank you @Niton I am using response.sendRedirect("C:\\Users\\Yugandhar\\Downloads\\data.xls"); but not downloading and simply redirecting to error page 'this site can't be reached'

Comment: Sorry for let waiting so long. You need to move/generate the file in the /Webcontent Folder